# Расшаренная директория на Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Есть виртуальная машина с Linux на VirtualBox. Были поставлены расширения для гостевой операционной системы; через настройки виртуальной машины создана общая папка. Однако, система её не видит. На гостевой попытки смонтировать папку не увенчались успехом. Система просто её не видит. Подскажите, как организовать шару между гостевой системой и хостовой? Кстати, буфер обмена тоже не работает.

Comment: Буфер обмена сначала надо включить в виртуалбоксе. Надеюсь, вы это сделали? 
Приведите текст ошибки при монтировании. Может вы неправильно указываете название шары?

Comment: @zenden2k, "Буфер обмена сначала надо включить в виртуалбоксе" - конечно сделано!)))

Comment: в гостевой операционной системе надо установить пакет, который содержит в названии/описании слова *virtualbox*, *guest* и *additions*.

Answer (score 1):

Когда устанавливаете гостевые дополнения в Linux, следите за ошибками сборки модулей ядра гостевых дополнений. Если необходимых пакетов в системе нет, расширения полноценно не будут установлены, следовательно и работать толком они не будут.
Доустановите требуемые пакеты и повторите установку гостевых расширений.

Для монтирования папки, можно использовать следующую команду:
`mount -t vboxsf -o rw,exec,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 ИМЯ_РЕСУРСА /ТОЧКА_МОНТИРОВАНИЯ`

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ!
Пробую: mount -t vboxsf -o rw,exec,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 myFolder /home. Получаю ошибку: **/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device**

Comment: Это потому что у Вас необходимые модули ядра не собрались при установке расширений, смотрите логи установщика.

Comment: **Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.**

Comment: @neo Об чём и речь, в гостевой ОС установите заголовочные файлы ядра и пакеты необходимые для сборки модулей ядра. Для своей ОС команды погиглите, не подскажу.

Comment: спасибо!))) Гугл нашёл полезную ссылку. Там как раз написано, как ставить пакеты для сборки модулей ядра: https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/dev_linux_modules.txt.html.